# One instance of an application without using windows APIs or MFC

Tags: c++

During interview I faced this weird question?
Can anyone let me know the answer

This is how it goes.
How can you run a single instance of an application using basic c++ only??

You cannot use any windows apis nor u can u use MFC.
You cannot manipulate registry....

Please let me know..this is an open question. and the interviewer challenged me to figure it out evn though the game was over and out..

Hope my question does nt offend the purpose of stack overflow...

Comment: Purely theoretical question but.. what about writing a file and clearing it when the app exits?

Comment: You can't, AFAIK there is no interprocess communication or locking mechanism inside the C++ Standard. You can come very far with files, but this won't make it atomic. Perhaps the best approach is start the app, then look if there are other instances started and kill yourself if there are other ones...

Comment: Yeah - where would you write the flag-file?

Comment: @Marco: I answered the same ..files approach as well as registry too..however both didnt help as i was told " Ok..what if I go and delete the reg entry or delete the file....

Comment: @nob:You wrote..Perhaps the best approach is start the app, then look if there are other instances started and kill yourself if there are other ones. The point is how to look for other instances..i googled but didnt get any..

Comment: I can atleast nail down the next freak who asks the same question :(

Comment: @user3819275 yes, but detecting other instances need files or some communication mechanism. If you want to get hacky you can also use covert channels (burning CPU performance) etc :)

Comment: i assume the whole point of the question is to figure out which hacky ideas are possible...

Comment: yeah and companies needs hackers......these days....sigh!!! Thanks anyways..all

Comment: how about using sockets?

Comment: 1) Wait for C++ to support sockets (C++17 perhaps) 2) Open a port 3) Profit

Comment: @Nick: No windows APIs..create sockets without windows APIs?

Comment: @user3819275 I don't know. The standard library, or any library, also uses windows APIs anyways so...

Answer (score 0):

So, I will follow my interpretation of what you posted:

> How can you **run** a single instance of an application *using basic c++*
>   only??

It's too open. Probably he was expecting you to make questions... like: "Ok, which platform will it run?". I believe this is the most important question.

What I understood is that he wants your *application executable* built using C++ and compiled to a platform, to run a single instance of *another* application (a second application), without syscalls, APIs, or whatever. It doesn't matter how **your** application was run, what matters is how you are going to run that *other application*. So it leads to another important question: "Which platform is this other application I am supposed to run compiled for?". If it's a Windows application, it *needs* to be run using Windows syscalls, because it has platform-specific dependencies. I say Windows here, but it would be the same for any widely used platform (like Unix).

I believe the most generic answer is: "Running (inline) ASM code in my application built using basic C++, being that the ASM code respects the instruction set of the processor where everything is running.".

More directly: Running it straight on the processor, using this second application instructions, using inline assembly.

**Edit - Adding another point of view:**

Another way, in case what he wants is to run just a single instance of the application **you did** (weird, but could be what he asked), is to compile your C++ application to a specific architecture, load (flash, depending on the platform) it to the processor memory, and start the processor. This is a "bare metal" approach, that is also a valid answer.